# Where do you put your rails app on your server? What User do you deploy with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've always deployed my apps to `~/apps/myApp/current` (with Capistrano, that's why I have the current directory).

But I've seen users deploy to like `/var/www/`, or even some make a directory at the root, `/myapp`.

I'm wondering is there an ideal place to put my app? Or does it not matter at all.

Additionally what do you usually name your user, I'm using `deploy` as my username and group, but I've seen users use `rails` or just whatever the username they always use is.

Is there a rule of thumb here? I'm aware that some may see this as a subjective question, I just wanted to get a little census as to what most people do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- On Ubuntu, `/srv` is a good place to install a rails app. Do not put it in `/var/www`, people would be able to browse your app sources in some circumstances.
- The user `www-data` is perfect for running your app (when running apache, that's the default user). With Passenger, you can set `PassengerDefaultUser www-data` in its config file to enable that.
  Do NOT run your app in as `root`. It's very dangerous.

Comment: It seems like running sites in `/var/www` is pretty standard, perhaps I'll create a directory at `/var/rails/myApp` or something.

Comment: @JoshuaPartogi, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15493352/10608 for why /srv is an appropriate place

Answer (score 2):

`/var/rails/app_name/current` and `deploy`

Answer (score 1):

I put all my web stuff under `/var/www/` just because I like having it all in one place and `/var/www/` is the default directory for Apache. There is no 'ideal' place to put your software - just put it wherever seems most logical to you. Pretty much the same for the username - I run my rails stuff under `www-data` but it doesn't matter what user you run it as (as long as it's not root).

Obviously clients shouldn't be allowed access to the rails app itself.

Answer (score 1):

/srv is the right place to put your http or ftp , for more info visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview